# Pass URL parameters to a redirect_to :root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably a really dumb question, but it's virtually impossible to google the answer...

Is it possible (and if so how...) to do something like:

```
redirect_to :root, :registered => true
```

Which would then link to http://myurl.com/?registered=true

The root url seems to strip all params. All I need it for is to track sign-ups via Google Analytics (I know I should probably be sending people to a thank-you page instead, but in this particular case - it makes more sense this way)

For this reason too - I don't want to redirect to something like:

```
:controller => :pages, :action => :home, :registered => true
```

As this will mess up both the analytics and SEO etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to redirect to pages#home? Where are you currently? Why would it hurt SEO?

Comment: From memory, it was so that I could count registrations via Google Analytics by checking for the ?registered=true in the url.

Comment: These days, I'd just use javascript to post an event direct to GA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
 redirect_to root_path(:registered => "true")
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple like that. Thanks.