# How to pass URL parameters to the root [in the routes.rb] in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameters

realize this question is similar to this one.

[Pass URL parameters to a redirect_to :root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382751/pass-url-parameters-to-a-redirect-to-root)

However, I'm wondering to start the application with parameters passed at the outset.  Perhaps root :to in the routes.rb file is not exactly the correct way to go?

Was basically hoping that it would start like this.

http://localhost:3000/controller?hello_id=1&finder_id=1&laser_id=1&sharks_id=4

Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you dreaming to pass these parameters to `rails server` or you just need to route root to that controller and action with such params? And why do you need this?

Comment: I am dreaming to pass the paramaters to the rails server :)

Comment: An example of why one would want to do this for the "but why????" crowd: say you are using kaminari. Say your root route is a frequently updated list, so by default you want to go to the last page. You can't go to the last page by default in the controller, because kaminari doesn't put "page=1" in the links to the first page. So, you want a root to: "my_list#index?page=last".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is impossible to do so in rails.

One way to workaround this is to point to an action of controller that will redirect to another action with all the parameters set (uglier solution, uglier solution in my opinion)

or

you can point to a controller that will set default values to the parameters if no parameters were passed.

Comment: Agree, I had an empty `#welcome` action in my `HomeController` as the root-route. I added `redirect_to user_path(current_user)` to this action since I wanted the first page for the user to be his/her profile page. This worked fine.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps it has changed in the last couple years, but this is definitely possible now:

```
root to: 'controller#action', hello_id: 1, finder_id: 1, laser_id: 1, sharks_id: 4
```

Comment: can these params be based on current user ?